# News Posts on Associated Sites not showing on Hub Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site, sharepoint-news

We have a hub site with web parts for news rollup that should be pulling in news posts from associated sites as they are added ;  it was working fine but now I am not seeing new posts from some sites.  The newest post is there on the associated site but only older 4 posts are showing on the Hub site web part.

Answer (score 0):

Is it for all users or specific users who are facing this issue?

Please verify - are you able to see the news from the below URL :

sites/vg/_layouts/15/news.aspx?title=All%20news

And you can do the below as well :

- Re-indexed the library
- Removed the webpart and add back
- Check the library permission.

Note :

- After re-indexing wait for at least a day for crawl to happen.

If above doesn't fix your issue, you may deassociate and reassociate back the site to the hub site from admin center.

If none of the above fix the issue, raise a ticket to Microsoft from office 365 admin center report.

Similar issue was raised by an user, in the below thread :

[News not visible for users at hub site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/news-not-visible-for-users-at-hub-site/m-p/234206)